# How can I add the values of a column based on a time interval of a day/month/year?

Tags: r, time-series, aggregate, data-manipulation

I was able to add the precipitation data on a daily basis (12:00 AM - 12:00 AM approx) using:

```
 pptnew<-data        
 pptnew<-aggregate(.~timestampDMY,data=pptnew, FUN = sum)
 #timestampDMY is a factor with Date Month and Year Values (made a factor      
 from POSIXlt using format argument to get rid of minutes/seconds) because 
 aggregate probably doesnot work on POSIXlt class.
```

But, now I want to add the values of a column (ie. precipitation in mm/30 minutes) based on a time interval - lets say 9:00 AM of one day until the 9:00 AM of the next day.

The following is a dummy dataset ([download](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16a0OO4UyIppU9EbNSqtbFn6kgrRjgDkxK4Qp23FHxzw/edit?usp=sharing)):

```
  Date_Time      Rainfall_mm
17-05-2013 19:00:00 0.8
17-05-2013 19:30:00 0.5
17/05/2013 20:00:00 0.3
17/05/2013 20:30:00 0
17/05/2013 21:00:00 0
17/05/2013 21:30:00 0
17/05/2013 22:00:00 0
17/05/2013 22:30:00 0
17/05/2013 23:00:00 0
17/05/2013 23:30:00 0
17/05/2013 00:00:00 1.3
18/05/2013 00:30:00 1.5
18/05/2013 01:00:00 1.7
18/05/2013 01:30:00 1.9
18/05/2013 02:00:00 2.1
18/05/2013 02:30:00 2.3
18/05/2013 03:00:00 2.5
18/05/2013 03:30:00 2.7
18/05/2013 04:00:00 2.9
18/05/2013 04:30:00 3.1
18/05/2013 05:00:00 3.3
18/05/2013 05:30:00 0
18/05/2013 06:00:00 0
18/05/2013 06:30:00 0
18/05/2013 07:00:00 0
18/05/2013 07:30:00 0
18/05/2013 08:00:00 0
18/05/2013 08:30:00 0
18/05/2013 09:00:00 0
18/05/2013 09:30:00 0
18/05/2013 10:00:00 0.6
18/05/2013 10:30:00 0.8
18/05/2013 11:00:00 0.5
18/05/2013 11:30:00 0
18/05/2013 12:00:00 0
18/05/2013 12:30:00 0
18/05/2013 13:00:00 0
18/05/2013 13:30:00 0
18/05/2013 14:00:00 0
18/05/2013 14:30:00 0
18/05/2013 15:00:00 0
18/05/2013 15:30:00 0
18/05/2013 16:00:00 0
18/05/2013 16:30:00 0
18/05/2013 17:00:00 0
18/05/2013 17:30:00 0
18/05/2013 18:00:00 0
18/05/2013 18:30:00 0
18/05/2013 19:00:00 0
18/05/2013 19:30:00 0
18/05/2013 20:00:00 0.3
18/05/2013 20:30:00 0.3
18/05/2013 21:00:00 0.7
18/05/2013 21:30:00 0.9
18/05/2013 22:00:00 1
18/05/2013 22:30:00 1
18/05/2013 23:00:00 
18/05/2013 23:30:00 
18/05/2013 00:00:00 
19/05/2013 00:30:00 
19/05/2013 01:00:00 
19/05/2013 01:30:00 
19/05/2013 02:00:00 
19/05/2013 02:30:00 
19/05/2013 03:00:00 
19/05/2013 03:30:00 
19/05/2013 04:00:00 0
19/05/2013 04:30:00 0
19/05/2013 05:00:00 0
19/05/2013 05:30:00 0.2
19/05/2013 06:00:00 0.2
19/05/2013 06:30:00 0.4
19/05/2013 07:00:00 0.7
19/05/2013 07:30:00 0.1
19/05/2013 08:00:00 0
19/05/2013 08:30:00 0
19/05/2013 09:00:00 0
19/05/2013 09:30:00 0
19/05/2013 10:00:00 0
19/05/2013 10:30:00 0
19/05/2013 11:00:00 0
19/05/2013 11:30:00 0
19/05/2013 12:00:00 0
19/05/2013 12:30:00 0
19/05/2013 13:00:00 0
19/05/2013 13:30:00 0
19/05/2013 14:00:00 0
19/05/2013 14:30:00 0
19/05/2013 15:00:00 0
19/05/2013 15:30:00 0.8
19/05/2013 16:00:00 0.5
19/05/2013 16:30:00 0.3
19/05/2013 17:00:00 0
19/05/2013 17:30:00 0
19/05/2013 18:00:00 0
19/05/2013 18:30:00 0
19/05/2013 19:00:00 0
19/05/2013 19:30:00 0
19/05/2013 20:00:00 0
19/05/2013 20:30:00 1.3
19/05/2013 21:00:00 1.5
19/05/2013 21:30:00 1.7
19/05/2013 22:00:00 1.9
19/05/2013 22:30:00 2.1
19/05/2013 23:00:00 2.3
19/05/2013 23:30:00 2.5
19/05/2013 00:00:00 2.7
20/05/2013 00:30:00 2.9
20/05/2013 01:00:00 3.1
20/05/2013 01:30:00 3.3
20/05/2013 02:00:00 0
20/05/2013 02:30:00 0
20/05/2013 03:00:00 0
20/05/2013 03:30:00 0
20/05/2013 04:00:00 0
20/05/2013 04:30:00 0
20/05/2013 05:00:00 0
20/05/2013 05:30:00 0
20/05/2013 06:00:00 0
20/05/2013 06:30:00 0.6
20/05/2013 07:00:00 0.8
20/05/2013 07:30:00 0.5
20/05/2013 08:00:00 0
20/05/2013 08:30:00 0
20/05/2013 09:00:00 0
20/05/2013 09:30:00 0
20/05/2013 10:00:00 0
20/05/2013 10:30:00 0
20/05/2013 11:00:00 0
20/05/2013 11:30:00 0
20/05/2013 12:00:00 0
20/05/2013 12:30:00 0
20/05/2013 13:00:00 0
20/05/2013 13:30:00 0
20/05/2013 14:00:00 0
20/05/2013 14:30:00 0
20/05/2013 15:00:00 0
20/05/2013 15:30:00 0
20/05/2013 16:00:00 0
20/05/2013 16:30:00 0.3
20/05/2013 17:00:00 0.3
20/05/2013 17:30:00 0.7
20/05/2013 18:00:00 0.9
20/05/2013 18:30:00 1
20/05/2013 19:00:00 1
20/05/2013 19:30:00 
20/05/2013 20:00:00 
20/05/2013 20:30:00 
20/05/2013 21:00:00 
20/05/2013 21:30:00 
20/05/2013 22:00:00 
20/05/2013 22:30:00 
20/05/2013 23:00:00 
20/05/2013 23:30:00 
20/05/2013 00:00:00 
21/05/2013 00:30:00 0
21/05/2013 01:00:00 0
21/05/2013 01:30:00 0
21/05/2013 02:00:00 0.2
21/05/2013 02:30:00 0.2
21/05/2013 03:00:00 0.4
21/05/2013 03:30:00 0.7
21/05/2013 04:00:00 0.1
21/05/2013 04:30:00 0
21/05/2013 05:00:00 0
21/05/2013 05:30:00 0
21/05/2013 06:00:00 0
21/05/2013 06:30:00 0
21/05/2013 07:00:00 0
21/05/2013 07:30:00 0
21/05/2013 08:00:00 0
21/05/2013 08:30:00 0
21/05/2013 09:00:00 0
21/05/2013 09:30:00 0
21/05/2013 10:00:00 0
21/05/2013 10:30:00 0
21/05/2013 11:00:00 0
21/05/2013 11:30:00 0
21/05/2013 12:00:00 0.8
21/05/2013 12:30:00 0.5
21/05/2013 13:00:00 0.3
21/05/2013 13:30:00 0
21/05/2013 14:00:00 0
21/05/2013 14:30:00 0
21/05/2013 15:00:00 0
21/05/2013 15:30:00 0
21/05/2013 16:00:00 0
21/05/2013 16:30:00 0
21/05/2013 17:00:00 1.3
21/05/2013 17:30:00 1.5
21/05/2013 18:00:00 1.7
21/05/2013 18:30:00 1.9
21/05/2013 19:00:00 2.1
21/05/2013 19:30:00 2.3
21/05/2013 20:00:00 2.5
21/05/2013 20:30:00 2.7
21/05/2013 21:00:00 2.9
21/05/2013 21:30:00 3.1
21/05/2013 22:00:00 3.3
21/05/2013 22:30:00 0
21/05/2013 23:00:00 0
21/05/2013 23:30:00 0
21/05/2013 00:00:00 0
22/05/2013 00:30:00 0
22/05/2013 01:00:00 0
22/05/2013 01:30:00 0
22/05/2013 02:00:00 0
```

Thank you in advance. (note there may be missing values for a day).

Regards
Sate

Comment: Apparently you want to calculate a moving/rolling sum. Package zoo offers a function for this.

Comment: Thanks, but I was unable to figure out how to use rolling sum for this? I require the total sum of rain from 9:00 am of one day until 9:00 am of the next day.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware there are multiple missing data points in your dataset?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df <- separate(df, Date_Time, c("dmyVar", "hmsVar"), sep = " ")

# see unique values available
unique(df$hmsVar)

# aggregate by timestamp, as you requested
df %>%
  group_by(hmsVar) %>%
  summarise(sumByHour = sum(Rainfall_meas_mm, na.rm = TRUE))
Source: local data frame [48 x 2]

     hmsVar sumByHour
      (chr)     (dbl)
1  00:00:00       4.0
2  00:30:00       4.4
3  01:00:00       4.8
4  01:30:00       5.2
5  02:00:00       2.3
6  02:30:00       2.5
7  03:00:00       2.9
8  03:30:00       3.4
9  04:00:00       3.0
10 04:30:00       3.1
..      ...       ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I think I have not been very clear. In the code you have given me, it is calculating the total rainfall for each time point, instead of the intervals of 9 hrs to 9 hrs. I want to add the rainfall values (which are recorded every 30 minutes), according to a time interval, from 0900 hrs of one day to 0900 hrs of the next day, instead of midnight to midnight. Midnight to midnight was easy for me to do because I can just aggregate them based on the date. But I could not aggregate them based on 9 to 9 because the dates change. .